# Highcharts - Tooltip and series name are out of their boxes in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, highcharts

I'm using highcharts 2.3.3 and I use the following code to describe the tooltip of the chart.

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        return '<b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %e, %Y', this.x) + '</b><br/>'+ this.y;
    }
},
```

The tooltip has no problem in firefox, but in chrome the text is shown out of the tooltip box.
I also have this problem with series name. The name is out of the box.
What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the problem was about my html file being right to left. I added left to right class and direction to my chart div and everything is ok now.

Answer (score 4):

if it dosent work you can set useHTML property of tooltip to ture,

```
  tooltip:{
      useHTML:true
    }
```